# Node.js Too Many UDP connections

Tags: node.js, docker, udp

I'm running a node/express app and it keeps dying randomly after a few hours.

The process is always still up, no logs or CPU/memory spikes or even much utilization but the process doesn't serve any requests anymore.

I suspect it's that the process has too many active UDP connections: `lsof -i -a -p X | wc -l` counted 9k+ network connections when I ssh'd into the docker-container running the node process, 98% UDP like this:
`node      6 root  223u  IPv4  614173      0t0  UDP *:63025
node      6 root  224u  IPv4  324249      0t0  UDP *:34622
node      6 root  225u  IPv4  415898      0t0  UDP *:44176`

The #connections grows at a rate of exactly 10 new connections per minute.

The only UDP-related functionality in my app is https://github.com/sazze/winston-logstash-udp

Details:

- Node v6.12.3 in Docker on AWS ec2 t2.medium
- This behavior started happening after migrating from a `debian:wheezy` Docker base image to `node:6.14.2-alpine`.

Questions:

1. How can I further debug each UDP connection? E.g. target, duration, ... That would help find the underlying problem.
2. What is the limit for node's connection limit? I've read 4096.
3. This problem didn't occur under debian, what differences are there that might be related?

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection. What you see in `netstat` is open UDP *ports*. You are leaking them somewhere, i.e. opening but never closing them.

Comment: @EJP Makes sense, yes - How can I track down what is allocating the port, any tracing tools that would be useful?